# Service / IntentService for uploading large(2 GB) files to server in android

Tags: android, service, intentservice

What should i use for uploading large file to the server ie service or intentservice.

*I feel like Intententservice is the right approach for uploading large file because*

1) It create is **own worker thread**,

2) No need to stop the service **automatically stopped** once uploaded.

*If I'm going for Service we do have some plus point mentioned below:*

1) We can **create a thread** within service for uploading large files

2) we can perform task in **parallel** while uploading if needed

3) If suppose Out of Memory(OUM) occurs while uploading the OS can **recreate our service** but for IntentService we don't have this privilege,i guess

**So guys please suggests your views which one should i use for uploading large files.**

Comment: are you going to inform the user in some way that data is being uploaded ? If thats the case , then use foreground service because even on low memory these services are avoided. So OS won't try to kill your service

Comment: Can we use foreground service alone or within intentservice?

Comment: Actually intentservice also extends Service class. So to use foreground service just create a normal service and inside that use startForeground method & pass id and notification object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Foreground service for a long running task. Because android gives more priority to foreground service than started service. Follow the below logic in android client side

1. Create a Service with thread implementation inside.
2. Make service as a foreground.
3. Try to set the chunk length in Http connection
4. Try to create the web service to support "resume upload"

To set the chunk size,

> httpurlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(buffersize)

By setting the chunk size, we can limit the internal buffering to avoid OOM.

To get a knowledge for implementing the resume upload option, refer
 [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/resumable-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I think the data is very large(2GB), It should be uploaded through `IntentService`.

**Why?** If you use `Service` then it will work in **parallel** no issue, but in any situation if you kill your app from background then your Service will stop  immediately.

> If you use IntentService then it will continue it's task until it finished, no problem if you kill the process from background. That is very important I think.

And the best Part you mention above that it works in different thread so there will be no effect on `MainThread`.

You should use IntentService, My Suggestion, Good Luck :)

Comment: Yes That's why I am suggesting to use `IntentService`, It will not stopped if you killed from the recent tab, but `Service` will be stopped.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion,I guess intentservice will also gets killed until we are not using some foreground service using notification,we can use this with service too,isnt it?

Comment: ForegroundService is much better than those two if you use it in `Service`. But I have Tested `IntentService`, it will not killed by killing recent apps, until finished its task.

Comment: In my case,the intentservice is alive till app is there in the recent tab but gets killed once we removed it from recent tab(for your knowledge we are not running any foreground service within the intentservice)